# Play Store downloads wrong arm apk

Tags: android, google-play, apk, platform

Got a weird problem on an app we've got in alpha testing on Google's Play Store. It's a massive apk file if you combine all the chip architectures (x86, arm...) so I split it into 4 separate apks (with individual version numbers as per the Google rules - I don't like having to do this but a 30MB apk is pushing it).

However, while I was testing, I noticed that the app ran MUCH faster when I side-loaded it (from the local PC) than when I downloaded it from the play store. The phone I use to test is a Samsung Note II and supports armeabi-v7. Unfortunately, when it connects to the play store, Google seems to pick the older armeabi apk to load on it. The latter runs but, without the floating point enhancements of the v7 code, the screen lurches around like a Zombie on gin.

Anyone know if there are any additional flags or 'hints' one can put in the manifest or elsewhere to force the v7 apk to devices that support it?

Comment: Is it worth even having the `armeabi` one, then, given the performance characteristics? Also, most ARM Android devices made in the past three years should be `armeabi-v7`-compatible, so I'm not sure that you'll lose all that much in terms of potential audience. And +1 for the vision of drunken undead. :-)

Comment: From my view the armeabi is just a pain; unfortunately "the powers that be" (shouldn't that be "the powers that are"?) reckon not having compatibility with old(er) phones will cut the market down so I'm stuck with building it (for now).